# Should Question Titles be Written Like Sentences or Titles?

Tags: discussion, title

When creating a new question, should it be written in the form of a title or sentence? For example, which of the following should be used?

"How to Save an Excel Sheet Twice in the Same Location"

Or...

"How do I save an Excel sheet twice in the same location"